# Reading a file from directory

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to read a file in the directory ./resources/input_file.utf8.
However, when I compile the following code from the terminal with the command:

```
 python namefile.py input
```

this error appears:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input'
```

This is my code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input_path", help="./resources/input_file.utf8")

    return parser.parse_args()


def foo(input_path):

    file_input = open(input_path, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') 
    for line in file_input:
    [...]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    predict(args.input_path)
```

One of the specification I have to respect is to not to put hard paths directly in the foo function, but only in the parser.add_argument() function.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try `python namefile.py resources/input_file.utf8`?

Comment: The path will be relative to the directory in which your terminal is. Make sure to provide a valid path from there.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a file 'input' in your directory

Comment: @DroidX86 It works! It is the only way to lunch this program? I mean I have always specify the directory before compile the file? The help in the ArgumentParser doesn't specify the directory yet? Thanks

Comment: @DobromirM yes, from the terminal I am in the right folder

Comment: @Sparky05 The input file exists and it is in the specified directory

Comment: @Pierfrancesco you have to tell the program where to find the file you're trying to use. You can do this either with a relative path or an absolute path. Absoute paths start from root `/`. Relative paths starts from either the current directory or a well-known location (like `~` - your home directory)

Comment: What is the full name of your data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the command `python namefile.py input`, make sure that:

1) **Files** - You have both your input file and the python script in the same folder.

2) **Location** - The working directory in you terminal is the one that contains the files (use **pwd** to check).

3) **File name** - Your filename is exactly `input` and **not** `input.txt` or `input.utf8`.

---

If your file is in the path that you have provided in your example, then you would need to call the script with that path.

**Example:**

`python namefile.py "./resources/input_file.utf8"`